# In jinja2 on Google App Engine, how can I (easily) build a URL based on a route name with arguments?

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2

If I construct a jinja environment as follows:

```
jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment (
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader ((os.path.dirname (__file__), 'templates')), extensions=[])
jinja_environment.globals['url_for'] = webapp2.uri_for
```

In my templates, I can build simple URLs from a route name when the route does not define any arguments:

```
{{ url_for('user_home') }}
```

However, when the route contains an argument as defined by a string such as `/invoice/<:\d+>`, I am unable to pass any arguments. Calling it in all the following ways fails, with a `KeyError "Missing argument "0" to build URI."`:

```
{{ url_for('invoice') }}
{{ url_for('invoice', args=['123']) }}
{{ url_for('invoice', kwargs={'__0__':'123'}) }}
{{ url_for('invoice',_request=None, args=['123'],kwargs={'__0__':'123'}) }}
```

Existing examples for this seem to be out of date--at least I haven't been able to make them work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Route('/invoice/<invoice_id>/', handler=invoice_handler, invoice_id='something')`

`{{ url_for('invoice', invoice_id=123) }}`

You can try the above, Jinja is expecting the named parameter you defined your handler.

Comment: and for adding get params: `{{ uri_for('home', o='ca') }}`

Answer (score 0):

I think just `{{ url_for('invoice', 123) }}` should work.

Comment: That doesn't work because the implementation of webapp.uri_for, to which the template global refers, is defined as: `def uri_for(_name, _request=None, *args, **kwargs):` and the 123 is interpreted as a request. But passing None as the request doesn't work either.